# Can the iOS 15 weather app change to have the old compact look(GUI)?

Tags: iphone, ios, weather.app

In iOS 15 the Weather app has a GUI redesign, which among other things makes the page much longer than in the old version. This mean more scrolling is needed to reach certain information.

Can it be switched to the old look or an equivalent compact layout on an iPhone size display ?

Comment: If the answer is no, can you upload a screenshot of the key data you want visible? We might be able to offer a widget solution or third party app that gets you exactly the data you seek.

Comment: Why is the word "shot" in the title?

Comment: Auto wrong went horribly astray and I failed to see the damage. Feel free to edit my posts (or any when they need a substantial fix. Shots fired indeed)

Comment: You can try to code your own widget with Scriptable app.

Answer (score 1):

No, Apple doesn't offer a way to customize the Weather app (except for choosing a city to display).

I'm extremely disappointed by this because there's some info that people in California, who coded the app, might want to see at the top, like Air Quality, that I couldn't care less about.

There's many different 3rd-party apps that provide a myriad of different layouts and you might find those more to your liking.